# Artillery keeps Giving me 400 Errors even though Unit Tests and Manual Testing Works

Tags: node.js, artillery

I am new to this, in a bootcamp trying to get a basic API in Node to work with testing. The routes all work, I have manually tested in Postman. The unit tests also all pass. But when I try and run a basic artillery (v 1.7.9) I get nothing but 400 messages. I dont know what Im doing wrong. Can anyone help? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLy7z.jpg)

I have unstalled and reinstalled the package, double checked that my key names are correct and double checked that my server is running.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.